# Is it better to maintain 3 small columns or 1 large column in a Table?

Tags: database, oracle

Three small number columns [Number(1)] >>

```
OptionA | 0/1
OptionB | 0/1
OptionC | 0/1
```

or one larger string column [Varchar2(29)] >>

```
Options | OptionA=0/1|OptionB=0/1|OptionC=0/1
```

I'm not sure about the way database handles tables, but I think that maintaining three columns as Number(1) is better than one column as Varchar2(29) !

-EDIT-

Let me explain the situation a bit more:

I am working on a common framework where the all incoming/outgoing request/response is tracked, these interactions can be channeled to a DB/File/JMS; now the all the configuration is being loaded from a table which has a column that corresponds to the output type, currently I'm using "DB=1|FILE=1|JMS=0" as the value of that column so that later if anyone wants to add this for their module they can easily understand what is going on, in my code I've written a simple logic which splits the string by "|" and then I use the exclusive or operator to switch between choice using a switch case..

Everything is already done but I don't like the idea of one large column is better than three small + it will remove the split string I'm doing.

-EDIT-

I finally got it clarified, there may be a situation where we have to add more options; in that case if we add the data column wise, it will result in modifying the table + changing the entity + adding more if's n all; on the other hand I ended up making an enum out of it in a simple bit wise logic to switch between options; this way, I need to modify the enum & add a new handler for the new option & then we are good to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a single column to store multiple pieces of data is probably the worst thing you can do in a database.

Violating first normal form has at least the following disadvantages:

1. **More difficult to query.** `OptionA = 1 and OptionB = 1 and OptionC = 0` versus `substr(options, 9, 1) = '1' and substr(options, 19, 1) = '1' and substr(options, 19, 1) = '0'`.
2. **Less flexable.**  What happens when you need to add another option?  Adding a new column is easy.  Adding a new format could mess up old queries.  For example, if someone tries to read OptionC with `substr(options, -1, 1)`.  (Although this is a good reason to use a 3rd option - a separate table.)
3. **No type safety.**  This can be a very subtle and tricky problem.  Let's say you write `substr(options, 9, 1) = 1` instead of `substr(options, 9, 1) = '1'`.  If anyone ever gets the format wrong, a single value could ruin lots of queries.  Or worse, it only intermittently crashes a small number of queries, because the access paths keep changing.  (Although you can prevent this with a check constraint.)
4. **Slower queries.**  Normally the amount of work done in an expression or condition isn't a significant cost for a query.  But adding a lot of unnecessary string manipulation can make a difference.
5. **Less optimizing.**  Oracle can only build efficient query plans if it can understand your data.  For example, let's say that OptionA is "0" 99.9% of the time.  When you filter `OptionA = 0`, Oracle can use a histogram make a very accurate prediction about the number of rows returned.  But for `substr(options, 9, 1) = '1'` you'll only get a wild guess.  If you have complicated queries using this columns you may spend a lot of time trying to "fix" the cardinality estimates.  (Although maybe expression statistics could help with this?)

There are times when denormalizing is a good idea.  For example, if you have terabytes of data, and compress the table, the single column may take up less space.  (But if you're trying to save space, why not use a format like "000" instead?).

If there really is a good reason for this, it definitely needs to be documented.  Perhaps add a comment on the column.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i've edited and added more info about the situation :)

Answer (score 1):

For a start, if I am reading your question right, you want each of the options to have one of just two possible values, correct?

If so then you could:

- have a separate integer (or boolean) column for each option
- have an `options` column that is a string of 1's and 0's, one digit for each options e.g. "001"
- use an 'options' column that is an integer and use a bit value for each options, e.g. optionA == options & 1, optionB == options & 2 etc.
- some databases have a bit vector data type which you could use.  For mysql there is the `BIT` data type, which can store bit strings up to 64 bits long.

There will be a trade-off between code complexity and efficiency for each of these.  Ask yourself, how much of the machine's time or storage will be saved by employing each of these options?  And how much of *your* time will be saved?

Comment: unfortunately Oracle does not support Boolean, i wanted to got for 3 columns with 0/1 but my senior says it will be better if i use 1 column.. and if i do that, i not only have to maintain a format which has to be explained to other team mates but also requires some coding to extract the values associated. but then again, i have no idea bout databases so i wanted some detailed explanation about the situation. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: ask your senior how many rows this table will likely have.  If he says anything under about a million, the "optimisation" is probably not worth it.

Comment: the table has 8 columns including the 1 large column.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance the 3 column approach is the one I would recommend, not only does this keep things simple in terms of extracting data, but should you ever wish you could set values against all 3 columns rather than being limited to one VarChar2 field.  If you opt for the single column VarChar2 then it is fairly simple to extract the info you need using the substr command or perhaps another variation, and although this isn't heavy work for an Oracle db, it does essentially put extra work on the server which is not necessary.

Comment: exactly my point, but how do i make the organisation realize this!

Comment: @DD_ Could you highlight why the organisation want to go with the 1 column approach, their reason behind it, we can then either agree or explain why we don't?

Comment: @DD_ Ah I see, in this case then, the single column approach will allow easier integration of further items, but I would re-think how you store them, I suggest rather than "Column A" etc using a unique code to identify each one and then perhaps using a delimter in between so you can split them when you need to see what's present.

Comment: i'm going for a format like: DB=1|FILE=1|JMS=0; where DB, FILE, JMS etc goes in my enum.